# Buttons in ListView DataTemplate's seem buggy

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm wondering if this is a potential bug in the framework. Button objects inside a ListView DataTemplate do not seem to generate unless one of these two conditions are met:

1. It is the only object.
2. It has a property bound to the item.

Example:

```
<ListView itemSource="{Binding SomeExampleCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding SomeStringProperty}" />
                    <Label Text="these 3 labels and button below APPEARS"/>
                    <Button Text="{Binding SomeStringProperty}"></Button>
                    <Label Text="Button below this label will NOT appear"/>
                    <Button Text="does NOT appear"></Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

As stated in condition 1, this will work / generate the button:

```
<ListView itemSource="{Binding SomeExampleCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Button Text="DOES appear"></Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Am I missing something in the documentation or something obvious? This seems buggy to me.

Environment Details:
Debugging a PCL Project in VS 2017 CE
Device: Samsung SM-G900V (Android 6.0 - API 23) Galaxy s5

Comment: What version of `Xamarin.Forms` are you using? Works fine for me: https://imgur.com/a/wH3Dr

Comment: @SushiHangover Good question! Turns out I was running 2.3.4.x so I upgraded to 2.5.0.121934 (latest stable). Aside from slowing VS studio down on the build (went from 30 seconds to 3 minutes EVERY TIME), it made zero difference. This appears that maybe i'm confused on the rowheight. It simply will not change regardless of what I do. Still working on this... finally this became obvious after moving things around and sometimes being able to see the top outline of the button. I've tried putting height properties everywhere and nothing seems to matter.

Comment: Have you tried setting HasUnevenRows to True?

Comment: @SteveChadbourne Wow. That was it. Odd thing is, i don't (have uneven rows). Each row is completely fixed. Right now I only have one single object in the collection (ItemSource) and had already tried setting the RowHeight manually which simply does not have any effect.

Comment: This does not seem to be behaving as specified: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.HasUnevenRows/

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using `HasUnevenRows="true"` if you don't absolutely need to since it will slow down your ListView's performance. All you should have to do is set RowHeight on your ListView to some value. For example:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeExampleCollection}" RowHeight="200">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding SomeStringProperty}" />
                    <Label Text="these 3 labels and button below APPEARS"/>
                    <Button Text="{Binding SomeStringProperty}"/>
                    <Label Text="Button below this label will NOT appear"/>
                    <Button Text="does NOT appear"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If the buttons still don't show up it is because your `RowHeight` isn't large enough. Depending on how long the text on your Labels are, when inside a ListView with a StackLayout, it will cut it off any other views if your RowHeight isn't big enough.

Also, it might be worth switching it from a `StackLayout` to a `Grid` with rows that you specify `Grid.RowDefinitions` and their `Height` to know exactly how large the ListView RowHeight should be.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeExampleCollection}" RowHeight="180">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="{Binding SomeStringProperty}" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="these 3 labels and button below APPEARS" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding SomeStringProperty}" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="3" Text="Button below this label will NOT appear" />
                    <Button Grid.Row="4" Text="does NOT appear" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: That absolutely does not work and I think it had to do with the ListView height itself (not the row height). Setting the RowHeight makes now difference whatsoever unless the ListView Height is set. HasUnevenRows for some reason seems to adjust after the Collection is bound/loaded?

Comment: Then next time provide your entire xaml layout instead of just a portion so we can accurately answer